# Tables and views keep on fetching in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am fairly new to MYSQL. I just today installed MYSQL on my Windows 10 computer for my personal learning. I installed mySQL workbench 8.0 and created some tables in the database. But the problem I am facing is the tables, views, stored procedures and functions are keep on fetching. I see some solutions online to run a linux command to resolve the problem. But mine is on windows and not sure where and how to execute the command. Can somebody please help me resolving the problem I am facing with MYSQL.

[image: MY SQL Fetching keep on going]

Comment: 'keep on fetching' - I'm not clear what you mean. Is this something that happens when you start mysqlworkbench?

Comment: Hi P.Salmon. I just not updated the question with the screenshot. The tables, views and other items in the database are not showed up,.. I just see them as fetching all the time.

Comment: Try accessing the MySQL server through command line `mysql` client and see if you can connect to it successfully or not, and do `show databases;`

Comment: In cases like this I would stop and restart everything. You can restart the mysql server from windows services. as a last resort you could kill from task manager.

Comment: HI P.Salmon, yes it works fine after closing and opening mysqlworkbench,.. thank you.

Comment: Hi Madhur Bhaiya, issue got resolved after closing and reopenning MYSQL,.. thanks you.

Answer (score 50):

Just restart your MySQL workbench and problem is solve.

Answer (score 13):

I think those files were written in macOS. When it loaded first time in workbench of windows, load then restart the workbench. Then the problem will be solved

Comment: Yes, you are right, because this is the dummy DB of a youtuber who is on macOS.

Answer (score 5):

Just close MySQL workbench and restart
it works!

Answer (score 1):

its most probably the same as I used when I learned MySQL from youtube. You just need to restart the workbench. This happens because it was originally in mac.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, just close the workbench window and open again, it most of the cases the problem will be solved.