# MySQL 8.0 Workbench hangs on fetching but can access tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I just downloaded the latest version of MySQL workbench and MySQL for windows 10. I'm working with a very small tutorial database. In the Schemas tab, some of the tables, views, stored procedures, and functions have "fetching..." next to them, which never resolves. Others do resolve. For the tables listed as "fetching..." I am able to work with them directly via SQL commands. I just can't browse them using the workbench. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tables and views keep on fetching in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57905821/tables-and-views-keep-on-fetching-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked by just closing the Workbench and reopening again.

Answer (score 0):

Does this persist with a refresh of the database (right click and select refresh/refresh all)?  IF so, that seems like either there's a lot of meta data that is clogging up the processing or perhaps an issue with the installation of the Workbench.  If it persists, especially with other datasets, I'd uninstall/reinstall.  Apologies for not being able to provide more!